# How to install ppa:nilarimogard/webupd8?

Tags: apt, ppa

I am trying to install Rubymine: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RGq6RKvEHJo , but when I try to type : `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:nilarimogard/webupd8` I get this error: `Error: retrieving gpg key timed out`. I tried to solve this by searching solutions here but I did get nothing and I posted this. 
This is what I get:

[image: error]

**UPDATE:** Solved this, https://www.linode.com/community/questions/17121/for-some-reason-rubygemsorg-is-not-available-when-i-try-bundle-install-or-ping-r

Comment: Tried again later? Launchpad is slow once in a while.

Comment: I can try again later, but..., why do we have to install Java for Ruby?  As far as I know they are separate stuff.

Comment: Maybe you want to consider to install RubuMine as a snap. https://makandracards.com/makandra/879-install-rubymine-under-ubuntu

Comment: Welcome to [ubuntu.se]! Please don’t put the solution into the question. Use the answer field below instead. https://askubuntu.com/help/self-answer However, answers should not depend on external links, see [answer] for details.